# jquery event bubbling and event.targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to get my head around how to stop a click event from bubbling up,out,down when a particular element is clicked.

```
<div class="clickable">
   clicking here shouldn't affect parents or children
    <div class="clickable">
       clicking here shouldn't affect parents or children
        <div class="clickable">
            clicking here shouldn't affect parents
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, if an element with the class "clickable" is clicked, I only want that item to be affected, toggling an even/odd class.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LDaA7/

When you run the fiddle and click a particular item, you'll see that various parents and children also get toggled.

From experimenting, event.stopPropagation(), returning false/true, .one, etc. impacts click events not targets per se. I may want other (unrelated) click events to work.

How do I target only the element I'm clicking?

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the target equals the bound element (`this`):

```
$("body").on "click", ".clickable", (event) ->
    if this is event.target
        clickTarget = $(event.currentTarget).closest(".clickable")
        clickTarget.addClass "clicked"

        if clickTarget.hasClass "odd"
            clickTarget.addClass("even").removeClass("odd")
        else
            clickTarget.addClass("odd").removeClass("even")
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LDaA7/1/)

Comment: Why not use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead of that `if` statement?

Comment: @muistooshort - that would be nicer, but the elements don't start with any of the classes, so toggleClass('odd even') isn't really an option the way it's written now, and coffescript isn't really my thing either.

Comment: I didn't notice the initial class problem, I'd probably force everything to start with sensible classes so that I could use the much more readable `toggleClass`. While I'm being nit-picking, you don't need `$(clickTarget)` when `clickTarget` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: @muistooshort - that's true, unwrapped the element, and the methods could be chained as well, but I really have no idea how you do it in cofeescript.

Comment: You'd do it the same way you'd do it in JavaScript. The "function calling" parentheses are (sometimes) optional but I always put them in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `$(this)` to target the element you have clicked. Also, `.stopPropagation()` so it won't bubble up the events.

**[See Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/chaitu18mhyd/BgcVj/)**

```
$('.clickable').click(function (e) {

    e.stopPropagation();
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.addClass('clicked');

    if (elem.hasClass('odd')) {
        elem.addClass('even');
        elem.removeClass('odd');
    } else {
        elem.removeClass('even');
        elem.addClass('odd');
    }
});
```